# React native init android,ios and app folder missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, git, react-native

[image]

Missing android,ios & app folders and index js files

I'm using `react native v 0.1.10` in windows 7 OS

Comment: Did you see any errors in the console when you ran 'react-native init'?

Comment: Nope, i didn't see any errors on my console.

Answer (score 26):

We can generate android and ios folder by  using `upgrade`

Run `react-native upgrade` to generate /ios and /android folders again.

Run `react-native link` for any native dependency. (if needed)

Finally run

`react-native run-ios`

or

`react-native run-android`

Comment: Really helpful. Thanks a lot dear

Comment: What if you never had any folders to begin with? How do you generate it? I am using yarn and am unable to find a straight answer. Thanks!

Comment: This does not answer the question - if you never had the folder it skips it  as mentioned in the comment above

Answer (score 0):

Probably you created your project using create-react-native-app, which is an even more simplified toolchain.

You should probably eject if you need android/ios native configs or something.

Please take a look at this doc: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md

Answer (score 0):

Try this to generate the Android and iOS folder without change version

```
react-native eject

react-native link
```

Answer (score 0):

Install a new file using powershell instead of cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Run following commands

```
1. npx react-native eject
```

After running above command you can see output in console as follows

```
info Generating the iOS folder.

info Generating the Android folder.
```

Next below command

```
2. npx react-native run-android
```

Answer (score -1):

Try update ur [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) and npm to the latest version then run everything again starting from init

Answer (score -1):

> npm run eject

next we will get some couple of questions,

> ? how would you like to eject  from create-react-native-app 
>   React-Native : I'd  like a regular react native project 
>   ? What should your app appear as on a users's home screen? _Your wish____ 
>   ? What should your Android Studio and Xcode projects be called? rncourse

After Ejected Successfully the project structure will change, added folders android and ios.

happy coding